# Application to download at specific time

Tags: windows, gratis, ubuntu, download-manager, bittorrent

I have to download a large-size torrent file but I have to download it at a specific interval of time.

I need an application that has the ability to start/stop the download in a torrent file in a preconfigured specific interval of time. That is, I want the file to start downloading at 12 a.m for e.g and pause at 6 a.m each day.

It should:

- Work for utorrent (Windows 8) or transmission (Ubuntu)
- Be free, or at least have a trial period with complete functionality (I'm going to use it only for once.)

Comment: You could just make a macro to do it for you, just an idea

Comment: (Vuze has so many more features than utorrent)

Comment: On Ubuntu (and other Linuxes), that's called [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) – and you create two jobs: one starts the torrent application at 12am, and the other "kills" it at 6 am :)

Comment: Yup, that’s how I would do it too. But, for those who insist on doing it withing the Torrent Client, with a nice API, there is explanation, with screenshots, of how to do it on 6 different clients at https://www.raymond.cc/blog/schedule-bittorrent-to-automatically-start-and-stop-downloading/    Btw, I am sure that this answers the question, but am reluctant to post an answer as I simply Googled for it. Otoh, if an answer is posted & awarded it will help others in future. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in utorrent itself:

press Shift+P and then select Scheduler, then click enable scheduling.
After that you can play with boxes to set when it should stop and when it should start. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

[BitTornado](http://www.bittornado.com/) is pure Python library written by John Hoffman - I am sure that you could make use of it and a few lines of python plus a cron task to kick it off.  *Unfortunately I cannot get to the documentation on it to tell you how as it is blocked from my current location.*